# using the GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop library, not able to drop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I am using the GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop library. But i implement everything , just simple so i can reorder my listbox, my code:

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableQuestions}" 

  dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
  dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" Margin="0,0,0,184" Background="#FF0BCE0B" />
```

AvailableQuestions is a list of Strings

but i am not able to drag and drop them ..
Someone who see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your binding collection 'AvailableQuestions' is an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) type. That should do the trick.